# What is the difference between [ValidateModel] and a check of valid state in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I see some code that for model validation uses:

```
 [ValidateModel]
```

and other code such as a sample WebAPI using this for model validation:

```
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference and why for example would the sample WebAPI apps from Microsoft not just use the [ValidateModel]?

Comment: Is ValidateModelAttribute an out of the box framework class? or are you working of a custom library?

Comment: There is no `ValidateModelAttribute` in MVC. Assume you referring to [this   plugin](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/TestMvcApplication/blob/master/MvcUtilities/FilterAttributes/ValidateModelAttribute.cs)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that you have `[ValidateModel]` attribute out of the box? Because [according to this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) it is custom attribute that helps make code a little bit cleaner, because you could omit `ModelState.IsValid` statement in the controller, because if action implemented its Model data is already valid. I browsed the internet and all `[ValidateModel]` implementations have similar `ModelState.IsValid` code statement:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure, but I think, because `[ValidateModel]` is custom attribute, which needs additional space for explanation and implementation, so most tutorials prefer out of the box `ModelState.IsValid`.